# How to do some code when fragments in a ViewPager appear and disappear

Tags: android, android-fragments, pager

In my android application I use a ViewPager with Fragments, and I Want to run some code when a Fragment appears (when a user can see it) and when Fragment disappear(when a user stop sees a Fragment)

I tried to override onPause(), onResume()
but the Fragments which do not appear in a UI run these methods anyway(I think this methods run when a Fragment is created.)

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    Log.i(TAG, "====onPause - " + phrase.getPhrase());
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.i(TAG, "====onResume - " + phrase.getPhrase());
    super.onResume();
}
```

I want to run some code only when a Fragment appears and disappears in UI.
But in my case each a new page creates this:

> ====onPause - I want you to take Tom to school.
>   ====onResume - Could I talk to you, Tom?
>   ====onPause - I know Tom wants to talk to you.
>   ====onPause - Could I talk to you?
>   ====onPause - Could I talk to you, Tom?
>   ====onResume - I know Tom wants to talk to you.
>   ====onResume - Could I talk to you?
>   ====onResume - Could I talk to you, Tom?

Comment: you can use viewpager adapter's OnPageChangeListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem this way:

```
  @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {

        if(phrase != null){
            if(isVisibleToUser){
                Log.i(TAG, "setUserVisibleHint" + phrase.getPhrase()+ "|isVisibleToUser " + isVisibleToUser);
            }else {
                Log.i(TAG, "setUserVisibleHint" + phrase.getPhrase()+ "|isVisibleToUser " + isVisibleToUser);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below method:-

```
override fun setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser: Boolean) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser)
    if(isVisibleToUser){
     // do something
      }

}
```